# Change action of Tab in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, key-bindings

Please help, I need that when i press the tab key to move to a new line, similar to pressing the down key. Any ideas how to do it?

I tried to use autocorrect, but I don't know how to denote the tab character.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions about Microsoft Word. For questions about using the program, please post questions at https://answers.microsoft.com or at SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

Just run the Sub ShortcutKeys() should be done.

```vb
Sub TabisDown()
    Selection.MoveDown
End Sub
Rem assign the shortcut key tab(wdKeyTab) to the active Document to run TabisDoow sub which just do what the down key do
Sub ShortcutKeys()
    'if below line use NormalTemplate ,then you should add the Sub TabisDown() code above
    ' to your Normal.dotm Templates which is locate in the directory whose address is "%AppData%\Microsoft\Templates"
    ' or you use ActiveDocument instead to save the two sub code in a .docm document.
    ' the first way it will appact/apply on/to all documents,the other just on/to the document where the code is saved
    CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument 'NormalTemplate 
  '  ThisDocument
    KeyBindings.Add _
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
        Command:="TabisDown", _
        KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyTab)
End Sub
```

**remark** *where to save and when to run is matter*

If you want to save in Normal.dotm you should run the sub in it's modules, not in a document's modules. If you run this sub in some document ,and the Sub TabisDown() is there, then the saved sub will be the one saved in that documents,not in the Normal.dotm, then you have to open this document in every time, or the shortcut will be set , but the Sub TabisDown() will not be found, this results in pressing tab key and nothing happen. Or you can rename the TabisDown sub to a specific name to prevent that name conflict with the name in a .docm document file.

*YouChat help me a corrected version of my text above with grammar and punctuation corrections:*

> If you want to save a macro in Normal.dotm, you should run the sub in its modules, not in a document's modules. If you run this sub in some document, and the Sub TabisDown() is there, then the saved sub will be the one saved in that document, not in the Normal.dotm. Then, you have to open this document every time, or the shortcut will be set but the Sub TabisDown() will not be found, resulting in pressing the tab key and nothing happening. Alternatively, you can rename the TabisDown sub to a specific name to prevent name conflict with the name in a .docm document file.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, thanks. I need TabisDown but not in all documents, so I will run it when necessary